# How to define a TEMPORARY TABLE as parameter in MYSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am trying to write a bulk insert functionality where I want to pass a `DataTable` from my ASP.NET Application to a Stored Procedure in MySql.

I created a Temporary Table in MySql like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE UNTF (

NotificationId int unsigned,
 NotificationMessage varchar(256),
 NotificationMessageTranslation varchar(256),
 CurrentUserId int unsigned
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

added data to it like this:

```
INSERT INTO UNTF
(NotificationId, NotificationMessage, NotificationMessageTranslation, CurrentUserId) values
(1,'test 2','test 2',178);
```

tried retrieving the data and it works, but I'm stuck at *how to define that temporary table as type in MySql stored procedure*

I tried to define it like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`enzodbadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ApplicationUserNotificationAddTest`
(           
    @PUNTF UNTF READONLY
    )
Begin
```

and this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`enzodbadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ApplicationUserNotificationAddTest`
(   

    @PUNTF InputTabel READONLY
    )
Begin
```

once I get it working I'll be calling that from my ASP.NET Application like this:

```
 DataTable dtUserNotification = CreateSampleUNTFTable();

            //base.ConnectionString

            //Open SQL Connection
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(base.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //Initialize command object
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ApplicationUserNotificationAddTest", conn))
                {
                    //set the command type  to stored procedure
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    //add parameter
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Products", dtUserNotification);

                    //execute the stored procedure
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

but I just can't get my SP working for a long long day, any help with this will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You can't mysql doesn't have that functionality.

Comment: @P.Salmon is there no way to send a table or a list of records to an SP in MySQL?